# Synth LaF Different Panel Styles

Tags: java, synth

i have an app with two JPanels and they must have different styles. I use the Synth LaF and I don't know how to have two different styles in one xml file. I define a style and bind it to "Panel" but then both panels look alike. Is there a possibility to define more styles and let synth know which one it should use on which panel?

Answer (score 1):

extracted from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html:

> The <bind> Element ...
>   type is either "name" or "region." If type is a name, obtain the name with the component.getName() method. ...

So, bind the style to a name, and give your panel names by calling setName